# I have VS2010RC and VS2008 installed - how can I run MVC 2 with both tools?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I just downloaded the release version of MVC 2, pretty excited about that!  Problem is, I can now create a MVC project in VS2010 but I don't seem to be able to do so in VS2008.

We are using VS2010 RC for our main project.  We need to use VS2008 for a new project so we can use the Connector/NET for MySQL, and I would love to be able to use MVC for this project.  Does anybody know if this is possible?  What am I missing, if anything?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to disagree with the other answer's line of discussion about this being impossible. I've been working heavily with MVC 2 RTM since it was released in VS2010 RC. Just now, just to see if I could do it since I saw this question, I was able to create a VS2008-based MVC2 project.

Because of this, I suspect you did not install MVC 2 RTM properly. You SHOULD have done the following (and I'm unsure about one step):

1. Uninstall "ASP.NET MVC 2"
2. ??? Uninstall "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2008 Tools"
3. Install the new RTM.

Like I said, I forget whether or not I did step #2 but some people are saying to do it when I google around about it now. I tried to find the blog post that I used to use but is.gd lost my link (grr...). However, despite what the others are saying, I am definitely able to do what you said.

....

The other option: You could always have somebody else who doesn't have VS2010 RC installed create the projects. The problem with 2008 should only be related to creating the projects and not necessarily working with the projects. Give that a try.

Comment: That may work if I ever had MVC 1 or 2 installed with VS2008.  I did not, so now I may be screwed.  I guess one solution may be to uninstall VS2010, install MVC2 to work with VS2008, then reinstall VS2010?  Sounds like a pain, but it may work...

Comment: BTW, I did do steps 1 and 3 -- the RTM will not install if the RC release is already installed.

Comment: Then perhaps step 2 is required and you missed that one. You should safely be able to just repeat steps 1, 2, and 3 again (this time step 1 will uninstall RTM instead of RC but that shouldn't matter) and maybe this will fix this for you. Seems like it should.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I read your second comment and totally missed your first one. :-P  What link did you use to get the RTM? Did you get it from here where it says it's for 2008? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en  That should have everything you need for both 2008 and 2010. I half wonder if maybe I skipped step 2 and my 2008 is using the RC tools while 2010 is using RTM tools. I'd be happy to check this out for you if I knew how to.

Comment: Ummm, I can't do step 2 because the MVC tools for VS2008 were never installed, so I can't uninstall them.  Thanks for the encouragement, though, I do appreciate it!

Comment: I responded before you posted the 2nd comment  :)  I got the tools using the Web Platform installer -- I will try the other site and see what happens.

Comment: Arrghh!! It's a darn good thing there's no video, or you could see the egg on my face.  I had been working on a project targeting Win 2k machines, using .NET 2.0 (as 2k doesn't support 3.5), and forgot to change that to 3.5 after I installed MVC...  When I selected .NET 3.5 for the project, MVC magically appeared as an option!
All is well, I can create and use MVC 2 projects in both VS2008 and VS2010RC.  So much for the nay-sayers, eh?

Comment: Excellent! Glad you figured it out even though I didn't help in any way other than to keep you motivated to keep trying! :-P

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. Quote from the release notes:

> Because Visual Studio 2008 and Visual
>   Studio 2010 RC share a component of
>   ASP.NET MVC 2, installing the ASP.NET
>   MVC 2 RTM release on a computer where
>   Visual Studio 2010 RC is also
>   installed is not supported

I guess you could wait 12 more days and throw away VS 2008 :-)

Comment: I read that quote, but it seems to address the RTM release and the RC release of MVC 2.  If you uninstall the MVC 2 RC release you CAN install the RTM release with the VS 2010 RC release.  I was hoping there was also a way to get it to work with both versions of VS...

Comment: Let's hope it really is just 12 more days.

Comment: @DaveN59, the scenario you are describing seems to fit exactly in the unsupported case.